# How to vary distance between siblings in TikZ graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

The example below renders a simple graph. I would like to branch with 1 cm to the left as default, but to branch a bit further in some cases. Say, I want f to branch 2 cm to the left. How would I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\tikz \graph[grow down, branch left=1cm]
  {  a
     -> { b
          -> { c
             , d
               ->[branch left=2cm] % this seems to be ignored
                  { e
                  , f
                  }
             }
        };
     d -> c;
     f -> e;
  };
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can act on the levels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\tikz
\graph[
  grow down, 
  branch left=1cm,
  level 2/.style={branch left=2cm},
  level 3/.style={branch left=3cm}
]
  {  a
     -> { b
          -> { c
             , d
               ->
                  { e
                  , f
                  }
             }
        };
     d -> c;
     f -> e;
  };
\end{document}
```

[image]